# Цикл в обратном порядке twig

Tags: twig

Есть обычный цикл

```html
{% for i in x %}
 {{loop.index0}} <br>
{% endfor %}
```

Выводит 0 1 2.
Как сделать чтоб выводило 2 1 0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{{loop.index0}}` - это текущая итерация цикла, начиная с нуля, поэтому эта переменная не даст вам `2,1,0`

а чтобы получить `2,1,0` нужно написать так:

```
{% for i in x %}
 {{loop.revindex0}} <br>
{% endfor %}
```

если же вам нужно вывести переменные в обратном порядке, то нужно использовать `reverse`:

```
{% for i in x | reverse %}
   {{ i }} <br>
{% endfor %}
```

Читайте официальную документацию, там много полезного:

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/tags/for.html
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/filters/reverse.html

Comment: полчаса назад официальная документация лежала.(